# Getting javascript to output calculation to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hey im having trouble getting my javascript to ouput my calculations into my html...

if you can please check my code and see where i might be going wrong thatd be great

```js
   var doorDesign_Prices= new Array();
  doorDesign_Prices["None"]=0;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP15"]=8.10;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP15 Deluxe"]=12.30;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP15 R"]=11.05;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP25"]=11.30;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP2525"]=13.35;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP35"]=11.30;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP45"]=13.90;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP55"]=17.85;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP5555"]=26.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP65"]=11.30;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP6565"]=13.60;  
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP85"]=17.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP95"]=11.30;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP9595"]=13.35;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP100"]=23.20;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP105"]=31.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP110"]=30.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP110110"]=35.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP181"]=21.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP185"]=21.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP190"]=10.10;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP200M"]=20.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP201M"]=20.75;
  doorDesign_Prices["PRP201MT"]=20.75;    

 function getDoorDesign() {
 var doorDesignSelect = document.getElementById('doorDesign');



 return doorDesign_Prices[doorDesignSelect.value];
 }


   var woodType_Prices= new Array();
  woodType_Prices["None"]=10.01;
  woodType_Prices["C. Pine"]=14.60;
  woodType_Prices["Cherry"]=7.00;
  woodType_Prices["Hickory"]=5.40;
  woodType_Prices["K Pine"]=24.00;
  woodType_Prices["Mahogany"]=12.51;
  woodType_Prices["Maple"]=7.46;
  woodType_Prices["Pt. Grade"]=18.16;
  woodType_Prices["R. Birch"]=9.18;
  woodType_Prices["Red Oak"]=13.12;
  woodType_Prices["Sapele"]=7.03;
  woodType_Prices["W. Ash"]=12.04;
  woodType_Prices["W. Oak"]=8.05;
  woodType_Prices["Walnut"]=11.05;

 function getWoodType() {
 var woodTypeSelect = document.getElementById('woodType');

 
 return woodType_Prices[woodTypeSelect.value];
 }


   var lipType_Prices= new Array();
  lipType_Prices["A"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["B"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["C"]=1.90;
  lipType_Prices["D"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["E"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["F"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["I"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["L"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["M"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["R"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["S"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["T"]=0.95;
  lipType_Prices["Z"]=0.95;  


 function getLipType() {
 var lipTypeSelect = document.getElementById('lipType');

 //alert(filling_prices[cakeSelect.value]);

 return lipType_Prices[lipTypeSelect.value];
 }


   var mouldType_Prices= new Array();
  mouldType_Prices["4/4"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["5/4"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["Deluxe"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["M"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["P"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["S"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["T"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["A"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["V"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["228"]=0;
  mouldType_Prices["MT"]=0;
  

 function getMouldType() {
 var mouldTypeSelect = document.getElementById('mouldType');

 

 return mouldType_Prices[mouldTypeSelect.value];
 }

   var panelType_Prices= new Array();
  panelType_Prices["A"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["B"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["C"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["D"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["E"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["F"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["M"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["O"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["Q"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["R"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["S"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["T"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["V"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["Rev C"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["Rev F"]=0;
  panelType_Prices["Bead"]=0;
  

 function getPanelType() {
 var panelTypeSelect = document.getElementById('panelType');

 

 return panelType_Prices[panelTypeSelect.value];
 }



   var gradeAndThickness_Prices= new Array();
   gradeAndThickness_Prices["None"]=0;
  gradeAndThickness_Prices["4/4 Standard"]=13.12;
  gradeAndThickness_Prices["4/4 Select"]=17.06;
  gradeAndThickness_Prices["5/4 Standard"]=17.06;
  gradeAndThickness_Prices["5/4 Select"]=22.17;
   

 function getGradeAndThickness() {
 var gradeAndThicknessSelect = document.getElementById('gradeAndThickness');


 return gradeAndThickness_Prices[gradeAndThicknessSelect.value];
 }




   var doorOptions_Prices= new Array();
  doorOptions_Prices["None"]=0;
  doorOptions_Prices["Finger Pulls"]=2.00;
  doorOptions_Prices["Hinge Holes"]=5.00;
  doorOptions_Prices["Lip As Pair"]=2.00;
  

 function getDoorOptions() {
 var doorOptionsSelect = document.getElementById('doorOptions');

 
 return doorOptions_Prices[doorOptionsSelect.value];
 }



function calculateTotal() {
 var total = getDoorDesign() + getWoodType() + getMouldType() + getPanelType() + getGradeAndThickness + getFinish + getDoorOptions;
 var totalEl = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

 document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Your Total is: $" + total;
} 

function hideTotal() {
 var totalEl = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
 totalEl.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<HEAD>
<script src="OrderForm.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
 <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="orderForm" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
         <div class="cont_order">
            <fieldset>        
            <table align=center border=0 width=300 cellpadding="1">
               <tr>
               <td>
                  <select id="doorDesign" name='doorDesign' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Door Design</option>
                    <option value="PRP15">PRP15</option>
                    <option value="PRP15 DELUXE">PRP15 DELUXE</option>
                    <option value="PRP 15 R">PRP15 R</option>
                    <option value="PRP25">PRP25</option>
                    <option value="PRP2525">PRP2525</option>
                    <option value="PRP35">PRP35</option>
                    <option value="PRP45">PRP45</option>
                    <option value="PRP55">PRP55</option>
                    <option value="PRP5555">PRP5555</option>
                    <option value="PRP65">PRP65</option>
                    <option value="PRP6565">PRP6565</option>
                    <option value="PRP85">PRP85</option>
                    <option value="PRP95">PRP95</option>
                    <option value="PRP9595">PRP9595</option>
                    <option value="PRP100">PRP100</option>
                    <option value="PRP105">PRP105</option>
                    <option value="PRP110">PRP110</option>
                    <option value="PRP110110">PRP110110</option>
                    <option value="PRP181">PRP181</option>
                    <option value="PRP185">PRP185</option>
                    <option value="PRP190">PRP190</option>
                    <option value="PRP200M">PRP200M</option>
                    <option value="PRP201M">PRP201M</option>
                    <option value="PRP201MT">PRP201MT</option>
                </select>    
                </td>
                  <td>
                  <select id="woodType" name='woodType' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Wood Type</option>
                    <option value="C. Pine">C. Pine</option>
                    <option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
                    <option value="Hickory">Hickory</option>
                    <option value="K. Pine">K. Pine</option>
                    <option value="Mahogany">Mahogany</option>
                    <option value="Maple">Maple</option>
                    <option value="Pt. Grade">Pt. Grade</option>
                    <option value="R. Birch">R. Birch</option>
                    <option value="Red Oak">Red Oak</option>
                    <option value="Sapele">Sapele</option>
                    <option value="W. Ash">W. Ash</option>
                    <option value="W. Birch">W. Birch</option>
                    <option value="W. Oak">W. Oak</option>
                    <option value="Walnut">Walnut</option>
                </select>
                </td> 
                  <td>
                  <select id="lipType" name='lipType' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Lip Type</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="I">I</option>
                    <option value="L">L</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                    <option value="R">R</option>
                    <option value="S">S</option>
                    <option value="T">T</option>
                    <option value="Z">Z</option>        
                </select>
                </td>  
                  <td>
                  <select id="mouldType" name='mouldType' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Mould Type</option>
                    <option value="4/4">4/4</option>
                    <option value="5/4">5/4</option>
                    <option value="Delue">Deluxe</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                    <option value="P">P</option>
                    <option value="S">S</option>
                    <option value="T">T</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="V">V</option>
                    <option value="228">228</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                  <td>
                  <select id="panelType" name='panelType' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Panel Type</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                    <option value="O">O</option>
                    <option value="Q">Q</option>
                    <option value="R">R</option>
                    <option value="S">S</option>
                    <option value="T">T</option>
                    <option value="V">V</option>
                    <option value="Rev C">Rev C</option>
                    <option value="Rev F">Rev F</option>
                    <option value="Bead">Bead</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                  <td>
                  <select id="gradeAndThickness" name='gradeAndThickness' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Grade and Thickness</option>
                    <option value="4/4 Standard">4/4 Standard</option>
                    <option value="4/4 Select">4/4 Select</option>
                    <option value="5/4 Standard">5/4 Standard</option>
                    <option value="5/4 Select">5/4 Select</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                  <td>
                  <select id="finish" name='finish' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Finish</option>
                    <option value="Clear">Clear</option>
                    <option value="Wheat">Wheat</option>
                    <option value="Fruitwood">Fruitwood</option>
                    <option value="Heartwood">Heartwood</option>
                    <option value="White Stain">White Stain</option>
                    <option value="Cinnamon">Cinnamon</option>
                    <option value="W. Prime">W. Prime</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                  <td>
                  <select id="doorOptions" name='doorOptions' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option>Options</option>
                    <option value="Finger Pulls">Finger Pulls</option>
                    <option value="Hinge Holes">Hinge Holes</option>
                    <option value="Lip As Pair">Lip As Pair</option>
                </select>
                </td>            
            </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>

 
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
  
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For now I just want to be able to output the calculations into my HTML before I make this form any more complicated.

Comment: what about wrapping your script code into a `window.onload = function(){/* HERE YOUR CODE */}` ?

Comment: What about debugging in a browser of your choice?

Comment: you should take care about providing values when select have not changed but are anyway involved in the calculation ();
you never show the result container; getFinish & getDoorOptions are not called as functions and getFinish as function doesn't even exists .......

Answer (score 0):

the variable *getFinish* is not declare at function *calculateTotal()*. so you should declare this variable or function before using it.

Answer (score 0):

in tag  remove onload='hideTotal()' it will output your javascript calculations into my html